# Is there a way to backup Evernote to Dropbox?

Tags: backup, dropbox, evernote

I'd like to be able to use a little bit of the space in my Dropbox account to create a backup of Evernote.  This way if anything happens to Evernote cloud service I'd still have access to the Dropbox backup.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Matt - Robert's answer is nice, except for the price tag, handing out account credentials to someone else, another point of failure, etc.  So far the answer I've provided is the only one that is free, doesn't require allowing someone else access to your credentials, and doesn't increase points of failure.

Comment: I was surprised that your solution works since wouldn't the Evernote database file be open all the time and Dropbox not able to sync it?  If Evernote wasn't running certainly this should work like a charm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My article at [wn7ant.com](https://wn7ant.com/2013/01/01/a-three-step-process-for-using-dropbox-as-a-backup-for-evernote-in-os-x/) explains how to do this using the App store version of Evernote:

1. Move `~/Library/Containers/com.evernote.Evernote/Data/Library/Application Support/Evernote` to `/Users/my_user_on_the_system/Dropbox`.
2. Create an alias of `/Users/my_user_on_the_system/Dropbox/Evernote`.
3. Move the alias of `/Evernote` back to `~/Library/Containers/com.evernote.Evernote/Data/Library/Application Support/`

Comment: It's just `~/Library/Application Support/Evernote` here. And a simple `ln -s "~/Library/Application Support/Evernote" ~/Dropbox/` in Terminal should get the same result (Dropbox follows symbolic links)

Comment: You may want to point out your connection to the website.

Comment: @patrix - You're not using the App store version, I am. Thank you for adding that though. +1

Comment: @Everett, I tried this solution, but when I move Evernote folder for any directory outside `~/Library/Containers/com.evernote.Evernote/Data`, the software considers an empty account and download the data from the server. When I move Evernote for other folders inside of this `Data`, it works properly.

Comment: This is the best solution IMO, it doesn't involve any third party services. The location of the notes may have changed in newer versions of Evernote. To find out where the database is located on your drive, open `Evernote > About` in the app Menu, then hold down the Option key on your keyboard. Click "Open Database Folder". Then just symlink like @patrix suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Using the ifttt.com service you can automate your evernote activity to dropbox.
Here is a recipe to use: https://ifttt.com/recipes/58926-evernotes

Comment: The article at wn7ant.com points out that the method I propose (in answering my own question) is more secure than handing out your credentials for Dropbox and Evernote to another service, and eliminates a point of failure (using another service).

Comment: @Everett while I agree with most of what you say, I believe it's actually better to **add a point of backup** by using this along with your method! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

One other way to achieve this is to use cloudHQ: http://cloudHQ.net service meant to replicate and synchronize data.

1. So cloudHQ can basically sync and replicate all your Evernote notes with Dropbox, GDrive or some other cloud services (we also support also Basecamp, Salesforce).
2. cloudHQ will export all you notes into TXT, ENEX, PDF, OpenOffice, and/or MS Word.
   Since our sync is continuous any change in Evernote will be immediately sync'd to Dropbox (or GDrive, Box, SugarSync, etc.)
3. You can do two-sync: so any change from GDrive/Dropbox will be automatically uploaded into Evernote
4. Even if you change Evernote via mobile or via web interface changes will be backed up immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Rich, the founder of Revert here. We provide free automatic daily backup for Evernote and a growing selection of other apps including Dropbox. Using Revert for backup takes the fuss out of the backup process and makes restoring notes or notebooks fast and easy.

[We were reviewed recently on The Next Web.](http://thenextweb.com/apps/2014/11/29/revert-makes-searchable-backups-cloud-services/)

[Give it a try](https://revert.io/sign-up) and if you have any questions feel free to ask a follow on question here.

Answer (score 0):

There is a product called Revert.io , it creates a backup for evernote, dropbox and some other cloud product and allows you to not only search across all of them but also restore. I think it is free for evernote users.